# Not displaying current time

Tags: javascript, html, time

```
 <script>
function updateClock() {
    var now = new Date();
    var time = now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds(); 
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = time;
    setTimeout(updateClock, 1000);
}
function check()
{
    var now= new Date();
    var h=document.getElementById('hour').value;
    var m=document.getElementById('minutes').value;
    if((now.getHours()==h)&&(now.getMinutes()==m))
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML="Alarm tone is playing";
    setTimeout(check, 1000);
}
function setAlarm(){
    var msg="Alarm is set for ";
    var ha=Number(document.getElementById('hour').value);
    var ma=Number(document.getElementById('minutes').value);
    var now=new Date();
    var hc=now.getHours();
    var mc=now.getMinutes();
    var nh=0,nm=0;
    if(hc>ha){
        nh=24-hc;
        //document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=nh;
        nh=nh+ha;
        if(mc>ma){
            nh--;
            nm=60-mc;
            nm=nm+ma;
        }
        else
            nm=ma-mc;
        msg=msg+nh+" hours "+nm+" minutes from now ";
        document.getElementById('alarmmsg').innerHTML=msg;
    }
    /*else if(hc==ha){
        if(mc>ma){
            nh=24-hc;
            nh=nh+ha;
            if(mc>ma){
                nh--;
                nm=60-mc;
                nm=nm+ma;
            }
            else
                nm=ma-mc;
            }
        }
        else{
            nh=0;
            nm=ma-mc;
        }
    }
    else{
        nh=ha-hc;
        if(mc>ma){
            nh--;
            nm=60-mc;
            nm=nm+ma;
        }
        else{
            nm=ma-mc;
        }
    }
    msg=msg+nh+" hours "+nm+" minutes from now";
    setTimeout(function(){
         document.getElementById("alarm").innerHTML=msg;
         },3000);*/
    check();

}
</script>
```

Above is the code for displaying current time, setting the alarm and calculating and displaying the time left for the alarm (alarm message).

On removing few comments from above code, here is the updated code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nancys/yj93tL68/)

It is not displaying the current time as well as the alarm message.

Is it because of multiple usage of setTimeout() or something else. Would really appreciate help.

Thank you.

Comment: It would really make your code more readable if you use slightly longer variable names and maybe try to move code that's almost the same to a function.

Comment: Two things. First, don't dump the whole code. Instead create a fiddle for people to check. Secondly, don't use that many options in the select control. There are better ways to allow selection, then selecting from a 60 item long dropdown. You can use number input instead.

Comment: @jitendragarg Thank you for your advice. May I know the better way to allow selection from 60 item list?

Comment: @Nancy use html input with type as number. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

Comment: @jitendragarg Not supported in IE8. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Nothing that I can think of off the top of my head. Check ui.stackexchange for ideas about UI. To be fair, programming side, you can generate this at runtime too. Or move the code to generate this server side. You can even call a calendar control, which provides implementation of number selector in IE8. As for UI, number is the best way to implement it.

Personally I will prefer to make my application work on all other browsers, which will break IE8 compatibility. :/ But, I know corporate love their old software.

Answer (score 0):

You have some missing braces in that massive IF statement:

These two lines specifically.

```
else
 nm=ma-mc;
```

Below is a corrected and functional mega IF

```
if(hc>ha)
  { nh=24-hc;
    //document.getElementById('display').innerHTML=nh;
    nh=nh+ha;
    if(mc>ma)
     {  nh--;
        nm=60-mc;
        nm=nm+ma;
     }
    else
     {  nm=ma-mc;
    //msg=msg+nh+" hours "+nm+" minutes from now ";
    //document.getElementById('alarmmsg').innerHTML=msg;
     }
  }
else if(hc==ha)
  { if(mc>ma)
      { nh=24-hc;
        nh=nh+ha;
        if(mc>ma)
         {  nh--;
            nm=60-mc;
            nm=nm+ma;
         }
        else
         { nm=ma-mc;
         }
      }
    else
     {  nh=0;
        nm=ma-mc;
     }
  }
else
  { nh=ha-hc;
    if(mc>ma)
     {  nh--;
        nm=60-mc;
        nm=nm+ma;
     }
    else
     { nm=ma-mc;
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working now. There is a little issue, I want the msg to be displayed for 3 seconds after the alarm is set. But, the message is not going off the screen. What could be the problem?

Comment: There is no code to erase the message that the alarm is sounding.

Add a timeout of 3000 to the "alarm tone is playing" IF statement which will erase the message.